# REACT NATIVE: How to make Drawer for whole screen

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-redux

I have a problem with Drawer , how can i put drawer for other my Views, it is just in Header - View,
i want to make it for all screen like in normal programms :
This is my App.js, here is located everything started from logic and design

Thank you!

```
 
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }}>     
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View >
         
          <Header /> //Header.js

              <View style={styles.row}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  placeholder="   Amount "
                  placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  keyboardType='numeric'
                  onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
                  value={text}
                />
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={selectedValue}
                  style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
                >

                  <Picker.Item value= " " label='Select Option' />
                  <Picker.Item label="Food" value="Food" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Transport" value="Transport" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Rent" value="Rent" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Other" value="Other " />

                </Picker>
              </View>
          <Text>TOTAL : {totalAmount}</Text>
         
              <Button
                title="Save"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                onPress={() => {        
                 
                  if (text == 0 ) {
                    alert('Please enter the Amount ')     
                       }            
                
                  if (text && selectedValue != " "){
                  setData([...data, { name: text, selectedValue: selectedValue }

                    ])
                  
                   setTotalAmount(totalAmount + parseInt(text))
                 
                }}
                }         
                
                 />
          
          <View styles={styles.list}>
                <FlatList
                data={data}
                        
              renderItem={({ item }) => <React.Fragment>
                <Text style={styles.item}> {item.name}$ Spend on "
                    {item.selectedValue}"</Text>

              </React.Fragment>}

              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

            />
</View>
            </View>
          </View>      
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)};
```

Here is my my StyleSheet.style //CSS

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  input: {
    margin: 15,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: 80,
    flex: 1,
  },
  input2: {
    margin: 15,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: 80,
   flex: 1,
  },

  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },

  item: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue'
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flex: 1
  },
});
```

And Finally this is my Header.js

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Button
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
                title="Go to notifications"
            />
        </View>
    );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
        </View>
    );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Header() {
    return (

        <View style={styles.header}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>

            <Text style={styles.title}>My expenses   </Text>


        </View>
        
    );

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        height: 480,
        paddingTop: 38,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        flex: 1
        
    },

    title: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        
    }

})
```

[image: I want to make my page normal , cause even Flatlist can't see , and Drawer is taking most of place]

Comment: I mean, you yourself put it in the `Header`, how can it be everywhere then? Do you have an `App` component, that container all of your other components?

Comment: Yes, and my App.js is over ther, i inserted to header.js, cause in my Aapp.js i could not see that , could help me with it, i mean how to make my drawer for the whole screen not only for the header?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No , cause if i am putting drawer into another place , i cant see it( , i dont know maybe too much views i have

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a general answer, I feel like I'm lacking some details, but let's try.
So basically your Drawer should be wrapping the whole of your app. Why? Because you don't care where you are navigating in the app, the drawer is a parent view to all of your navigation. It is just there, present always throughout the app.

Therefore, it would look like this.

`App.js`

```
<Drawer
  content={<LateralContainer />} // this for me is the drawer that I actually display to the user
  open={props.lateralOpen && ...} // define when it is open
  disabled={!props.userId} // define when it is disabled
  ...
>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar />
    <HeaderContainer
      ...
    />
    <AppNavigatorContainer
      ...
     />
       ...
  </View>
</Drawer>
```

So `Drawer` encapsulates everything, not just your header of whatever you have.
Hope this helps, if not let's continue debugging this.